# Find Matrix representation of Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Given $\beta = ${$1,x^2,x$} and $\gamma = ${$(1,1), (1,0)$},

$T: P^2(\Bbb{R}) \to \Bbb{R}^3 $ is $ T(a + bx + cx^2) = (a + b, a + c)$, calculate $[T]_\beta^\gamma$.

I just need confirmation that I'm not crazy and that there is a typo - the transformation maps to $\Bbb{R}^2$ right?

And how do I calculate $[T]_\beta^\gamma$? I've never been good at this. Do I transform it through $\beta$ then $\gamma$?

Edit: After tips from Lem.ma, I got

$T(1) = (1,1) = 1(1,1) + 0(1,0)$

$T(x^2) = (0,1) = 1(1,1) + -1(1,0)$

$T(x) = (1,0) = 0(1,1) + 1(1,0)$

So,  $[T]_\beta^\gamma$ = $\begin{bmatrix} 1&1&0\\0&-1&1 \end{bmatrix}$ ?

Comment: Yes, the transformation is to $\mathbb{R}^2$ - that's why you are given a basis (that is, $\gamma$) in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Also, the recipe for constructing the matrix that represents the linear transformation is the same for all linear transformations on all linear spaces: Apply the linear transformation to each of the basis vectors in the "from" space, decompose the result with respect to the basis in the "to" space, and organize the resulting coefficients as columns of the matrix.

Comment: Please check edit :)

Comment: Yes, looks good! Well done. But the important thing is to understand why this matrix "works": that is, translates component of a vector to the components of its image.